# inline-block elements alignment issue

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/z3Jue/20/

I cannot get all of my (inline-block) elements to align to the top of their container div.

I've tried these items in a list, floated left (but cannot center) and a lot of other random things but nothing seems to work.

Any help appreciated!

**CSS**

```
#buttons{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    border:1px dotted black;
    height:60px;
}

 .block img{

    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    height:60px;
    width:40px;
    border:0;

 } 

.block{
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:60px;
    width:40px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
 }

 #search {
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    height:60px;
    width:240px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
 }

#searchTextForm{
    font-size:16px;
    width: 185px;
    color:#333;
    margin-top:3px;
    border:1px dotted blue;
    margin-top:15px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttons" align="center">
<div id="search" >
    <form method="get" name="tipue" action="search/results.html" target="toolbarlongTOC" title="search">
    <input type="text" id="searchTextForm" name="d" class="field" size="25" >
    </form>
</div>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">

    <a href="#" id="bookmarks">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cbb92jF.jpg">
    </a>

    </div>
<div class="block">3</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `.block {vertical-align: top}`. Done.

http://jsfiddle.net/z3Jue/22/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `height` to your parent `div` you can use `line-height` and use `vertical-align` to the child blocks. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z3Jue/25/